# Counting rings of order $p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, ring-theory

[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html) states that there are exactly 52 rings of order 8 (multiplication in rings may be not commutative and perhaps there will be no neutral element) and 53 rings of order $p^3$ where $p$ is an odd prime. However this does not match what one can find at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A027623) -- according to a paper cited there (by Antipkin/Elizarov) there are $50+3p$ rings of order $p^3$. So who is wrong and why?

Comment: I think its worth pointing out that the number listed in the series in OEIS is also 52. So in that regard MathWorld and OEIS agree.

Comment: Yes, but they disagree for $p=3$.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. I apologize. You're absolutely correct.

Comment: R. Raghavendran, Finite associative rings, Compositio Mathematica vol 21 no 2 (1969) p 195-229 (referenced from the OEIS page you link) claims that there are 11 rings with identity of order 8 and 12 rings with identity of order $p^3$ for odd prime $p$, so the discrepancy of $3(p-1)$ rings of order $p^3$ between the two sources presumably relates to rings which don't have an identity.